# Sending mail in PHP via Mail::factory sometimes will timeout my page

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am a JS developer so PHP is really not my expertise.
I have a page that sends an email when submitted, sometimes the page will timeout when gmail servers are slow to respond.

I am wondering if there is a way to either extend the timeout of a page (I am using LAMP setup, Apache, PHP) or maybe run Mail::factory in aysnc non blocking?

or any other ideas to make sure the page does not timeout to users (I don't mind if they need to wait 10 more seconds as they see loading bar...) when gmail is slow to reply back?

this is the function

```
function sendMail($from, $to, $subject, $body, $type = "HTML", $attach = "", $attachType = "'image/jpg'") {

       $crlf = "\n";
       $mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));

        #if ($type == "text") {
        # $mime->setTXTBody($body);
        #} else {
        $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
        #}

        $headers = array(
            'From' => "<from.gmail.com>",
            'To' => $to,
            'Subject' => $subject
        );

        $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
                'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'port' => '465',
                'auth' => true,
                'username' => 'que@aaa.com',
                'password' => 'xxxx'
            ));

         //$to = 'Recipient Name <my_user@gmail.com>';

        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
        $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      //echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
     } else {
      //echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
     }
}
```

Thanks,

Sean.

Comment: Start using a reasonable email provider, I'd say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove execution timeout completely limit by adding

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

At the very top of your script.

[Here is the link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to PHP documentation on this function.

Comment: cant write enough characters to explain why this solution is awful. 
you should never use this solution on a production server unless you don't mind having such big exploit on your server.users could send you unresolved dns records and until you wont hit you're curl timeout the script will keep running and if you wont set a curl timeout as well you're server will just keep trying to communicate with their server forever until it eventually crash.

you should really be careful every time setting unlimited timeout,that might solve the current issue but will probably make a bigger one later

Comment: @Gal, you have a valid point there, but given the context I find it totally acceptable.

Comment: @GeorgyIvanov according to what he wrote,he has no experience in back-end development,so I doubt hes aware to any kind of security risks like the one you're putting him atm.

Answer (score 0):

Why send your emails asynchronously? Use a queue service to send emails in the background instead.

Answer (score 0):

Install a local mail server, send using SMTP to localhost. It will complete very quickly and the mail server will deal with waiting, queuing, retrying etc without you having to implement anything complicated. SMTP is not good during page loads because it can be very slow. You can configure the mail server to relay onwards via your gmail account. I recommend postfix.